# LibGDX NullPointer Exception when trying to load Music

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, libgdx

I'm working out of the book *Learning Libgdx Game Development* on Chapter 10 dealing with adding music and sound to the game. I tried Googling around to see if anyone else came across the same null pointer issue with adding the music but no luck.

Essentially trying to load in a Music track from a different class called Assets to run in my main game.

I see the assets are loaded, it prints out on the console. So I don't think it is an issue with not finding the file.

```
com.woodgdx.game.Assets: # of assets loaded: 9
com.woodgdx.game.Assets: asset: ../core/assets/sounds/jump_with_feather.wav
com.woodgdx.game.Assets: asset: ../core/assets/canyonbunny.pack.png
com.woodgdx.game.Assets: asset: ../core/assets/music/keith303_-_brand_new_highscore.mp3
com.woodgdx.game.Assets: asset: ../core/assets/sounds/live_lost.wav
com.woodgdx.game.Assets: asset: ../core/assets/canyonbunny.pack2.png
com.woodgdx.game.Assets: asset: ../core/assets/sounds/pickup_feather.wav
com.woodgdx.game.Assets: asset: ../core/assets/sounds/jump.wav
com.woodgdx.game.Assets: asset: ../core/assets/canyonbunny.pack.atlas
com.woodgdx.game.Assets: asset: ../core/assets/sounds/pickup_coin.wav
```

So I'm not really sure what is going on...

The error itself is..

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.woodgdx.game.woodGdxGame.create(woodGdxGame.java:29)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:147)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
```

Main class

```
package com.woodgdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Application;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager;
import com.woodgdx.game.Assets;
import com.woodgdx.game.screens.MenuScreen;
import com.woodgdx.game.util.AudioManager;
import com.woodgdx.game.util.GamePreferences;

/**
 * The main game file with the main
 * engine methods
 * @author xxxx
 */
public class woodGdxGame extends Game
{
    @Override
    public void create()
    {
        // Set Libgdx log level
        Gdx.app.setLogLevel(Application.LOG_DEBUG);
        // Load assets
        Assets.instance.init(new AssetManager());
        // Load preferences for audio settings and start playing music
        GamePreferences.instance.load();
        AudioManager.instance.play(Assets.instance.music.song01);
        // Start game at menu screen
        setScreen(new MenuScreen(this));
    }
}
```

The error occurs on this line..

```
AudioManager.instance.play(Assets.instance.music.song01);
```

My Assets class contains this inner class. The way the book had it, I got the same error when I made it it's own class.

```
    /**
     * Music for game loaded
     * @author xxxx
     *
     */
    public class AssetMusic
    {
        //Our music object
        public final Music song01;

        /**
         * Retrieves the music file for the music
         * @param am
         */
        public AssetMusic(AssetManager am)
        {
            song01 = am.get("../core/assets/music/keith303_-_brand_new_highscore.mp3", Music.class);
        }
    }
```

Then here is the AudioManager class they does play a little role in here.

```
/**
 * Manages the playing and organization
 * of audio files
 * @author xxxx
 *
 */
public class AudioManager
{
    public static final AudioManager instance = new AudioManager();

    private Music playingMusic;

    // singleton: prevent instantiation from other classes
    private AudioManager()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Play sound with default vol, pitch, and pan (0)
     * @param sound
     */
    public void play(Sound sound)
    {
        play(sound, 1);
    }

    /**
     * Play sound with default pitch and pan (0) but different vol
     * @param sound
     * @param volume
     */
    public void play(Sound sound, float volume)
    {
        play(sound, volume, 1);
    }

    /**
     * Play sound with default pan (0) with different pitch and vol
     * @param sound
     * @param volume
     * @param pitch
     */
    public void play(Sound sound, float volume, float pitch)
    {
        play(sound, volume, pitch, 0);
    }

    /**
     * Plays sound with a vol, pitch, and pan activated
     * @param sound
     * @param volume
     * @param pitch
     * @param pan
     */
    public void play(Sound sound, float volume, float pitch, float pan)
    {
        //If sound is muted, dont play
        if (!GamePreferences.instance.sound)
            return;
        sound.play(GamePreferences.instance.volSound * volume, pitch, pan);
    }

    /**
     * Plays music on loop
     * @param music
     */
    public void play(Music music)
    {
        stopMusic();
        playingMusic = music;
        if (GamePreferences.instance.music)
        {
            music.setLooping(true);
            music.setVolume(GamePreferences.instance.volMusic);
            music.play();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Ends the music loop of doom
     */
    public void stopMusic()
    {
        if (playingMusic != null)
            playingMusic.stop();
    }

    /**
     * Checks settings for muted music, vol level
     */
    public void onSettingsUpdated()
    {
        //No music available
        if (playingMusic == null)
            return;
        //Sets volume
        playingMusic.setVolume(GamePreferences.instance.volMusic);
        //Checks if music is not muted
        if (GamePreferences.instance.music)
        {
            //If music isn't playing, play it
            if (!playingMusic.isPlaying())
                playingMusic.play();
        }
        //Mute music if selected so
        else
        {
            playingMusic.pause();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use encapsulation, but regardless the issue is that `Assets#music` is null, as nothing else is dereferenced on that line that isn't a constant (I'm assuming `Assets#instance` is made the same way as `AudioManager`)

Comment: Ah ok, yeah it ended up being something with the initialize method that Libgdx has. Yea I've basically been copying the books code, with other courses I'm taking and all I don't have time to make it fancy and put in good soft engineering principles for it.

Comment: Thank you for your help though, led me the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to add in the music and sound for the initialization for the Assets class. I was thinking it was something with the files but it just wasn't initialized.

Add this to the init() method of Assets

```
sounds = new AssetSounds(assetManager);
music = new AssetMusic(assetManager);
```

Comment: And now that you know the solution to a NullPointerException, please try to solve that particular exception before posting to StackOverflow. The cause is always the same